# Using get_param to get the value of a cell

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to set the name of a custom block to the name of an an InputSignal coming off of a bus selector.

I have used `get(get_param(gcb, 'object'))` and found out that there is a parameter, `InputSignalNames` that is a cell.  Is there anyway to get the cell name in a single command?

I see that I can do

```
tmpName = get_param(gcb, 'InputSignalNames')
signalName = tmpName{:}
```

But is there something like

```
get_param(gcb, 'InputSignalNames'){:}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the following help?

```
set_param(gcb,'Name',strrep(strrep(char(get_param(gcb,'InputSignalNames')),'<',''),'>',''));
```

Or if you don't need to remove the <>,

```
set_param(gcb,'Name',char(get_param(gcb,'InputSignalNames')));
```

Comment: I am wanting to get it in one line

Comment: I edited the above answer to do this in one line, and it passes some basic tests. Hope it works for you.